# .Net Framework vs .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a question for an app I am building. Let me start with there is no code with this app as of yet. I am still in the design stage.

My question is for more informative purposes. I am building a C# WPF application for my work that will be primarily Label printer, keeping logs on the server as well as a few other things.

I have heard .Net Framework 4.8 is the last update. Everything is going to .Net Core 5. My question is since Win11 is coming out. Would it be beneficial to build in .Net Core?

Is Win11 migrating to .Net Core and dropping .Net Framework? The reason why I am asking this is simply not to redo the programming on an unsupported infrastructure.

I will be updating all computers at work to Win11 eventually. However our software is only compatible with Win7. So I got put in charge with an overhaul.

So the biggest thing is using the right infrastructure that has continued updates.

Any advice is helpful.

Comment: If you don't have any strong reason (e.g. an "old" library or hardware not supported) to stick with .NET 4.8, I'd definitely recommend going with .NET 5 / 6 (out in Nov 2021). It's the current place to be - why stick to an old, soon-to-be-deprecated platform? ....

Comment: Using latest technology is always a great choice, there are multiple reason for this, but I the highest important reason is its support by vender(Microsoft), and I would suggest you wait and choose. Net 6 as you are in your discovery phase of your project.

Comment: The application we use at the moment the software was written 20+ years ago. So I am overhauling 6 different apps into one and have all info streamlined to a server, which they want to go with cloud server eventually. So the program will be used in 6 different departments then once it gets to shipping all data input is filled in a the QC just prints the data we need. So the performance has to be top shelf. That’s why I was asking that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a combination of .NET Standard and .NET 5.

--

.NET Framework

- Old school, only create new .NET Framework code if you have to.
- *Mostly* Windows-only unless you emulate with Mono or something similar.
- Can reference .NET Standard and .NET Framework.

.NET Standard (used for compatibility)

- Always cross-platform
- Can only be used to create libraries, not executables.
- Can reference .NET Standard

.NET Core (still modern, but will eventually give way)

- *Usually* cross-platform, but with a few exceptions.
- Can reference .NET Standard and .NET Core

.NET 5 (latest as of when this is written)

- *Usually* cross-platform, but with a few exceptions.
- Can reference .NET Framework, .NET Standard, .NET Core, and .NET 5.

.NET 6 (in preview, releasing November 2021)

- *Usually* cross-platform, but with a few exceptions.
- Can reference  .NET Framework, .NET Standard, .NET Core, .NET 5+, and .NET 6.

Comment: That’s actually a good answer comparing all of the pros and cons. My biggest thing is I have been programming in .Net Framework and the design in .Net 5 is the same but with a few differences. So I will have to look into the .Net 5 structure. I noticed references have changed to dependencies. Which is not a problem. The structure of the solution has changed a little bit. I have never done .Net 5 applications so I am guessing it’s a  small learning curve from what I am used to

Comment: They have a Visual Studio extension called the .NET Portability Analyzer that will examine your .NET Framework app and tell you what parts, if any, are not on .NET Core.  It made converting my .NET FW app to .NET Core a whole lot easier.    And once I was on .NET Core, going to .NET 5 was practically a no-op.